# How to convert Text to Vector without extraneous allocations

Tags: haskell

I have a question about the most efficient way to convert `Text` to `Data.Vector.Unboxed.Vector`. I've been playing with it using the `weigh` benchmarking tool like this, and I've been seeing a lot of extraneous allocation:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}
module Main (main) where

import Control.Monad
import Data.String.Interpolate
import Data.Text as T
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as VU
import Weigh

testFunc :: Int -> Text -> Weigh ()
testFunc inputSize text = wgroup [i|#{inputSize} characters|] $ do
  func' "VU_fromList" VU.fromList (T.unpack text)
  func' "VU_fromListN" (\t -> VU.fromListN (T.length t) (T.unpack t)) text

main :: IO ()
main = mainWith $
  forM_ [10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000] $ \n -> do
    let !text = T.replicate n "0"
    testFunc n text
```

In my results, converting 10 characters to a vector requires 256 bytes of allocation. Converting 100k characters requires 1M bytes. I think this is happening because I use `T.unpack` and the compiler creates intermediate list elements in memory. Isn't there a way to just allocate a vector of the desired size, and traverse the text while copying stuff over?

Could I perhaps use the [Data.Vector.create](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.13.1.0/docs/Data-Vector.html#v:create) function? But I couldn't find a way to traverse a `Text` monadically...

Full benchmark file and results here:

https://gist.github.com/thomasjm/7c2bd4f25ba4a75e90b898a902725ead

EDIT: oh, I forgot to mention there is a method that actually works, but is quadratic time. It's this:

```hs
generateMethod :: Text -> VU.Vector Char
generateMethod t = VU.generate (T.length t) (T.index t)
```

This method uses just about exactly 4x bytes, where x is the number of characters, as you would expect for UTF-8.

Comment: Some allocation will be hard to avoid because you must reencode from UTF-8/16 (depending on `text` version). But perhaps you can encode to UTF-32 `ByteString` with platform endianness and then construct the vector directly from that with `unsafeFromForeignPtr`, to save some copying.

Comment: I don't think any re-encoding needs to happen. AFAIK a `Vector Char` is a vector of 4-byte chunks, each large enough to hold a UTF-8 character, so constructing the vector should just involve copying them over. Btw, I just added an edit showing a no-allocation method that is quadratic time. All I need now is a linear time approach.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean about UTF-32, that does seem like a good idea actually. I'm looking into doing that now but I'd rather avoid unsafeness.

Comment: I added several more attempts to the Gist. I thought I had it with the simple and elegant "`VU.unfoldr T.uncons`" but that still allocates 2.5x the optimal amount.

Comment: Since `text-2.1`  the internal representations are the same. You can access them via `Data.Text.Internal` and `Data.Vector.Primitive`. I guess something in the line of `func (TInternal.Text bytearray off len) = VPrimitive.Vector off len bytearray` is a good starting point

Comment: What exactly is wrong with the working method using quadratic time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main problems:

1. We need to traverse the text, but the text API does not provide a function that use-case directly.

   - For example `T.uncons` does not work, the maybe and the tuple can be optimized away in most cases, but the allocation of the remaining text is usually not optimized away (although it did seem happen with `VU.unfoldr`).
2. We need to build up the vector, but the vector API does not provide a function which allocates the whole vector in one go.

   - All functions, even `VU.unfoldrN` seem to grow the vector in the process. I think that is because that implementation strategy is amenable to fusion, but it does mean you trade in a bit of efficiency.

To resolve 1, I've opted to use the internal stream representation directly which does allow you to write efficient traversals.

To resolve 2, I've chosen to manually create a mutable vector as you also already pondered.

```
...
import Data.Text.Internal.Fusion
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed.Mutable as M

streamCreateMethod :: Text -> VU.Vector Char
streamCreateMethod t =
  case stream t of
    Stream step s0 _ -> VU.create $ do
      m <- M.new (T.length t)
      let 
        go s i =
          case step s of
            Done -> pure ()
            Skip s' -> go s' i
            Yield x s' -> do
              M.write m i x
              go s' (i + 1)
      go s0 0
      pure m
```

Benchmark results (using `tasty-bench` and `+RTS -T` which is my preferred way of benchmarking):

```
  10 characters:     OK
    32.8 ns ± 2.6 ns, 111 B  allocated,   0 B  copied, 6.0 MB peak memory
  100 characters:    OK
    228  ns ±  21 ns, 471 B  allocated,   0 B  copied, 6.0 MB peak memory
  1000 characters:   OK
    2.15 μs ± 179 ns, 3.9 KB allocated,   0 B  copied,  10 MB peak memory
  10000 characters:  OK
    21.1 μs ± 1.5 μs,  39 KB allocated,   2 B  copied,  10 MB peak memory
  100000 characters: OK
    211  μs ±  14 μs, 386 KB allocated,  21 B  copied,  12 MB peak memory
```

(for the memory usage, look at the allocated amounts, not the peak which is over the run of the whole program including multiple iterations.)

---

Jon Purdy proposed solution to use `encodeUtf32LE` and `unsafeFromForeignPtr`, so I tried that too:

```
encodeMethod :: Text -> VS.Vector Char
encodeMethod t = 
  case encodeUtf32LE t of
    BS ptr len -> 
      runST $ VS.unsafeFreeze $ 
        VSM.unsafeFromForeignPtr0 (castForeignPtr ptr) (len `quot` 4)))
```

But that performs much more poorly:

```
  10 characters:     OK
    281  ns ±  24 ns, 3.3 KB allocated,   0 B  copied, 6.0 MB peak memory
  100 characters:    OK
    2.32 μs ± 181 ns,  31 KB allocated,   2 B  copied, 6.0 MB peak memory
  1000 characters:   OK
    22.3 μs ± 1.8 μs, 302 KB allocated,  20 B  copied, 6.0 MB peak memory
  10000 characters:  OK
    221  μs ±  11 μs, 3.0 MB allocated, 212 B  copied, 6.0 MB peak memory
  100000 characters: OK
    2.31 ms ± 169 μs,  30 MB allocated,  85 KB copied, 7.0 MB peak memory
```

---

I've now created a pull request to the `text` library which adds `foldlM` to the public API:

https://github.com/haskell/text/pull/543

Comment: Looks great, I ran some time benchmarks as well and found `streamCreateMethod` to be a bit faster than `VU.unfoldr T.uncons`